# Twitter query all from this account, but this account only with this hashtag

Tags: twitter, tags, feed

I have recently made a Twitter feed reading all tweets from for example: @Steve @John and @Company.

For which I generated this query:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:steve+OR+john+OR+company&callback=TweetTick&rpp=50

Now I want to display all the tweets from @company, but for @John and @Steve only the tweets containing #company, is there, or isn't there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to do this within a single query. Your best bet is to either:

- filter the tweets on your end (discard any tweets from @John or @Steve without company), or
- combine the results of two separate queries (one for @Company, one for #company from:@John OR from:@Steve).